# Python DataFrame to_csv Errno 13 Permission denied

Tags: python, dataframe, export-to-csv, permission-denied, user-permissions

I'm working on Windows 10, Python code is executed in Spyder (Python 3.7).
Writing does not work in my main file folder (D:/main_file_folder), however it works on the higher level (D:) or just created folders (D:/just_created).
I tried to open Spyder with administrator privileges.
I tried to remove writing protection in the destination folder properties, but the writing protection tick returns eventually, once I check the properties again.
I tried to give the user all privileges in the folder properties security tab. It sticks, but has no effect.

```
dest = Path('D:/anyfolder/file.csv')
some_pandas_df.to_csv(dest, encoding="utf-8")
```

*File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 428, in get_handle
f = open(path_or_buf, mode, encoding=encoding, newline="")*

*PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:\main_file_folder\file.csv'*

Comment: Have you checked the file you are saving is not open?

Comment: Yes. It's closed.